# Angular slide-toggle not responding to after confirm popup

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a problem where I'm trying to have a popup that confirms removal("are you sure you want to untoggle") before a toggle has been untoggled. As of this moment if a user untoggles the slider, the popup does appear, but the toggle untoggles automatically, instead of waiting for the users response.

I've attempted:

- Disabling the toggle (while it appears on) before the popup by [disabled] = isDisabled and then forcing true and false in function...it does disable th function, but it does it before the popup and disables it off.
- Tried turning the value of checked to true before and/or after the popup for example [checked] = isChecked and then forcing true and false in function
- I previously used a (change), but thought that the function would only run after the value changed, and changed it to (toggleChange)
- I tried giving the toggle an id, and then forcing clicks by id.click()

Here is the HTML

```
<mat-slide-toggle id="pingSlider" (toggleChange)="onTogglePing()" [disabled]="disablePingToggle" [checked]="isToggledPing"> </mat-slide-toggle>
```

Here is the TS file

```
onTogglePing(): void {
    if (!this.isToggledPing) {
      this.isToggledPing = true;
      this.formControlName.addControl('ping', this.pingFormGroup);
    } else {
      this.disablePingToggle = true;
      this.showConfimFormControlRemoval().then(
        res => {
          if (res) {
            this.formControlName.removeControl('ping');
            this.isToggledPing = false;
          }
        },
        err => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          }
        }
      );
    }
}

showConfimFormControlRemoval(): Promise<any> {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ConfirmActionModalComponent, { size: 'md', centered: true });
    modalRef.componentInstance.title = this.util.getTranslated('remove_configuration');
    modalRef.componentInstance.message = this.util.getTranslated('profile_confirm_modal_msg_reset_user');
    modalRef.componentInstance.primaryButtonText = this.util.getTranslated('confirm');
    return modalRef.result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a way to delay the activation of the slider until the user chooses from the dialog, you can use `(click)` and `(keypress)` events instead of `(toggleChange)` so you can use `$event.preventDefault()` to stop the control from responding to the user event:

```html
<mat-slide-toggle 
  [checked]="isChecked"
  (click)="onToggleChange($event)"
  (keyup.space)="onToggleChange($event)">
</mat-slide-toggle>
```

```js
  onToggleChange($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    
    if(this.isChecked) {
      this.dialog.open(ModalComponent).afterClosed().subscribe(
        confirmed => { if(confirmed) this.isChecked = false; }
      );
    } else {
      this.isChecked = true;
    }

  }
```

Here's a simplified [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66782706?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)